# definition of open sets in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For metric spaces, the definition of an open set $U\subset X$ is that it is a set which for any point $u\in U$ in the set there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B_\epsilon(u)\subset U$.
My question is where is the effect of the mother metric space X?

Comment: What do you mean by *the effect of the mother metric space X*?

Comment: you do not have any Effect of mother metric space as you do not have any child space... If you have $U\subset X$ fixed and you want to define open sets in $U$ then you have effect of mother space on open sets of $U$ as induced from $X$.. Otherwise there is no mother.. no child...

Comment: I am talking about that suppose we have to show U is open in X. Then we have to prove every point in U is an interior point of U i.e B(x,r)$\subset U$. In showing this will I need any influence of the mother space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of points in the open ball $B_\epsilon(u)$ depends on the *ambient* space $X$. That is, if we considered $Y \subset X$ with $U \subset Y$, then it is not necessary that $B_{\epsilon,X}(u) = B_{\epsilon,Y}(u)$. For example, if $Y = U$, then $B_{\epsilon,Y}(u)$ is by definition contained in $U$.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the euclidean metric with

1. $U =[0,1)$ ; $X= \Bbb R_+$ including $0$
2. $U =[0,1)$ ; $X= \Bbb R$

In first case $U$ is open because of $X$. We cannot move outside $0$ to find the neighborhood around $0$ because of $X$. Thus there exist a positive $\varepsilon$ such that $( 0, +\varepsilon)$ lies entirely in $U$: this can be checked for other points in $U$ as well.

Second case, $U$ is not open as there is no $\varepsilon$ such that $(-\varepsilon,+\varepsilon)$ lies entirely in $U$.